# Passing variables from middleware to page in Next.js 12 new middleware api

Tags: next.js

### Background to the Question

Vercel recently released their biggest update ever to Next.js. [Next.js blog](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12).
They introduced a lot of new features but my favorite is `Middleware` which:

> "enables you to use code over configuration. This gives you full
> flexibility in Next.js because you can run code before a request is
> completed. Based on the user's incoming request, you can modify the
> response by rewriting, redirecting, adding headers, or even streaming
> HTML."

### The Question

The following structure is used in this question.

```
- /pages
    index.js
    signin.js
    - /app
      _middleware.js # Will run before everything inside /app folder
      index.js
```

The two important files here are `/app/_middleware.js` and `/app/index.js`.

```js
// /app/_middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req, event) {
  const res = { isSignedIn: true, session: { firstName: 'something', lastName: 'else' } }; // This "simulates" a response from an auth provider
  if (res.isSignedIn) {

    // Continue to /app/index.js
    return NextResponse.next();
  } else {

    // Redirect user
    return NextResponse.redirect('/signin');
  }
}
```

```js
// /app/index.js

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Authenticated!</h1>
      
      // session.firstName needs to be passed to this file from middleware
      <p>Hello, { session.firstName }</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example `/app/index.js` needs access to the `res.session` JSON data. Is it possible to pass it in the `NextResponse.next()` function or do you need to do something else?

In express you can do `res.locals.session = res.session`

Comment: You'd need to use `getServerSideProps` in that page to access `res.session`. You can't access it directly from the component itself.

Answer (score 4):

We found a solution for 12.2+ middleware - published here:

https://clerk.dev/blog/nextjs-pass-value-from-middleware-to-api-routes-and-getserversideprops

And copying here for posterity...

Usage: middleware.js

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { withContext } from "./context";

// Pre-define the possible context keys to prevent spoofing
const allowedContextKeys = ["foo"];

export default withContext(allowedContextKeys, (setContext, req) => {
  setContext("foo", "bar");
  return NextResponse.next();
});
```

Usage: API route (Node)

```js
import { getContext } from "../../context";

export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ foo: getContext(req, "foo") });
}
```

Usage: API route (Edge)

```js
import { getContext } from "../../context";

export default function handler(req) {
  return new Response(JSON.stringify({ foo: getContext(req, "foo") }));
}
```

Usage: getServerSideProps (Edge and Node)

```js
import { getContext } from "../context";

export const getServerSideProps = ({ req }) => {
  return { props: { foo: getContext(req, "foo") } };
};
```

Source: (saved to context.js on your root)

```js
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

const ctxKey = (key) => `ctx-${key.toLowerCase()}`;

export const getContext = (req, rawKey) => {
  const key = ctxKey(rawKey);

  let headerValue =
    typeof req.headers.get === "function"
      ? req.headers.get(key) // Edge
      : req.headers[key]; // Node;

  // Necessary for node in development environment
  if (!headerValue) {
    headerValue = req.socket?._httpMessage?.getHeader(key);
  }

  if (headerValue) {
    return headerValue;
  }

  // Use a dummy url because some environments only return
  // a path, not the full url
  const reqURL = new URL(req.url, "http://dummy.url");

  return reqURL.searchParams.get(key);
};

export const withContext = (allowedKeys, middleware) => {
  // Normalize allowed keys
  for (let i = 0; i < allowedKeys.length; i++) {
    if (typeof allowedKeys[i] !== "string") {
      throw new Error("All keys must be strings");
    }
    allowedKeys[i] = ctxKey(allowedKeys[i]);
  }

  return (req, evt) => {
    const reqURL = new URL(req.url);

    // First, make sure allowedKeys aren't being spoofed.
    // Reliably overriding spoofed keys is a tricky problem and
    // different hosts may behave different behavior - it's best
    // just to safelist "allowedKeys" and block if they're being
    // spoofed
    for (const allowedKey of allowedKeys) {
      if (req.headers.get(allowedKey) || reqURL.searchParams.get(allowedKey)) {
        throw new Error(
          `Key ${allowedKey.substring(
            4
          )} is being spoofed. Blocking this request.`
        );
      }
    }

    const data = {};

    const setContext = (rawKey, value) => {
      const key = ctxKey(rawKey);
      if (!allowedKeys.includes(key)) {
        throw new Error(
          `Key ${rawKey} is not allowed. Add it to withContext's first argument.`
        );
      }
      if (typeof value !== "string") {
        throw new Error(
          `Value for ${rawKey} must be a string, received ${typeof value}`
        );
      }
      data[key] = value;
    };

    let res = middleware(setContext, req, evt) || NextResponse.next();

    // setContext wasn't called, passthrough
    if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
      return res;
    }

    // Don't modify redirects
    if (res.headers.get("Location")) {
      return res;
    }

    const rewriteURL = new URL(
      res.headers.get("x-middleware-rewrite") || req.url
    );

    // Don't modify cross-origin rewrites
    if (reqURL.origin !== rewriteURL.origin) {
      return res;
    }

    // Set context directly on the res object (headers)
    // and on the rewrite url (query string)
    for (const key in data) {
      res.headers.set(key, data[key]);
      rewriteURL.searchParams.set(key, data[key]);
    }

    // set the updated rewrite url
    res.headers.set("x-middleware-rewrite", rewriteURL.href);

    return res;
  };
};
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a another way but just like using cookie to achieve this. Just pass you data through `headers`.

```js
// middleware.ts

async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const response = NextResponse.next();
  response.headers.set('X-HEADER', 'some-value-to-pass');
  return response;
}
```

```js
// _app.ts

function MyApp({ data }) {
  // you can access your data here
  <div>{data}</div>
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = ({ ctx }) => {
  const data = ctx.res.getHeader('X-HEADER');
  ctx.res.removeHeader('X-HEADER');
  return { data };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

[According to the examples](https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/edge-functions/jwt-authentication) (look specifically at `/pages/_middleware.ts` and `/lib/auth.ts`) it looks like the canonical way to do this would be to set your authentication via a cookie.

In your middleware function, that would look like:

```js
// /app/_middleware.js

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req, event) {
  const res = { isSignedIn: true, session: { firstName: 'something', lastName: 'else' } }; // This "simulates" a response from an auth provider
  if (res.isSignedIn) {

    // Continue to /app/index.js
    return NextResponse.next().cookie("cookie_key", "cookie_value"); // <--- SET COOKIE
  } else {

    // Redirect user
    return NextResponse.redirect('/signin');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but as far as I know you should not store user information in cookies. It can easily be manipulated by the end-user. A better solution I thought about is to create a store using reacts `createContext`

Comment: This was a simple example, if you were implementing a cookie based approach you would probably want to either encrypt the cookie itself, or store a JWE in the cookie.

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me try to find a workaround a solution. But shouldn't it be a default way to do this?

Comment: Should it? Sure, it's be a great feature, but someone asked [this same question in the RFC](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/29750#discussioncomment-1537361) but it hasn't been answered, leading me to believe that it is not possible at this time. My assumption is they got the MVP set for Next12/Nextconf. Hopefully this feature is on a roadmap (or someone else can prove me wrong and it is possible).

Comment: This does not work in Next 12.3.2 cookies, body, etc are all read-only on request.

Answer (score 1):

Only weird solution is to inject your custom object into req.body because next.js v12 middleware doesn't allow altering the `NextApiRequest`

```js
export const middleware = async (req: NextApiRequest) => {
  //   return new Response("Hello, world!");
  req.body = { ...req.body, foo: "bar" };
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  await middleware(req);
  // now req.body.foo=='bar'
}
```

They do however explain how you can extend [middleware here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares#extending-the-reqres-objects-with-typescript), but the example given (copied below) isn't meaningful enough because it doesnt show how `withFoo()` is implemented

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { withFoo } from 'external-lib-foo'

type NextApiRequestWithFoo = NextApiRequest & {
  foo: (bar: string) => void
}

const handler = (req: NextApiRequestWithFoo, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  req.foo('bar') // we can now use `req.foo` without type errors
  res.end('ok')
}

export default withFoo(handler)
```

I assumed based on the above, withFoo.ts should be like this. But still wasn't successful in accessing request.Foo()

```js
import { NextApiHandler, NextApiRequest } from "next";


export const withFoo = (handler: NextApiHandler) => {
  //do stuff

};
```

Maybe someone can chip in?

Comment: close. Here's the shape you're looking for. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14415#discussioncomment-42291

Comment: How to do this with a Page, instead of an Api handler?